# How to make a conditional mailto in html from a dropdownmenu

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, conditional-statements, mailto

I have produced a dropdownmenu in html and want to make a mailto that sends an email to a different emailadress, depending on the choice made in one of the dropdownmenu's.

I am not familiair with htmlcode, so my knowledge on conditional mailto's that refer to a choice made in the dropdownmenu is limited. I have tried finding a code that refers the mailto to the options in de dropdownmenu, but can't find one.

Any tips?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what dropdown menu ? list menu or select input ?

Comment: you will need a bit of javascript to achieve it, so after change of value in select you grab the value and create a mailto link, then insert it into your link or do whatever you want with it